# Firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber success but no sms (using react)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting to the success block of this code here:

```
   firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(`+${userPhone}`, appVerifier)
    .then(confirmResult => {
      console.log(confirmResult);

    }).catch(err => {alert(err);})
```

It console logs the confirmResult just fine and I have waited a long time now and no SMS, I have tried this with 2 different phone numbers as well. Any clue what is going on?

Comment: did u enable phone number authentication in the firebase console?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled and my domain is added as well.

Comment: Are you providing the phone number correctly in E.164 format? For example US phone numbers: +11234567890

Comment: For example I have the U.S phone number +18123339999

Comment: Any solution here @TaylorAustin

Comment: @TaylorAustin How are you generating `appVerifier`? I need help regarding it.

Comment: @sridharreddy did you find any solution for how to getting appVerifire

Comment: Hey @TaylorAustin are you solve it?